# Substantivierte Adjektive: das Dunkel vs ein Arbeitsloser

Tags: declension, nominalization

In der aktuellen April-Ausgabe von *Deutsch Perfekt* geht es um das substantivierte Adjektiv *Dunkel*:

> Plötzlich waren wir in einem Wald. Das war vielleicht ein tiefes
> Dunkel.
>
> Irgendwann kamen wir aus dem Dunkel heraus und waren plötzlich in
> einem kleinen Ort.

Deklination:

Nom.: das Dunkel
Gen.: des Dunkels
Dat.: dem Dunkel
Akk.: das Dunkel

Ich nehme parallel ein weiteres substantiviertes Adjektiv auf:

Nom.: das Rot
Gen.: des Rots
Dat.: dem Rot
Akk.: das Rot

Ich kann mir nicht erklären, warum die Wörter *das Dunkel* / *das Rot* wie Substantive dekliniert werden, während *ein Deutscher* / *ein Jugendlicher* / *ein Angestellter* etc. wie Adjektive dekliniert werden, wenn beide Wortarten als substantivierte Adjektive gelten. Kann es daran liegen, dass *das Dunkel* / *das Rot* etwas Abstraktes bezeichnen?

Was mir auch unklar ist: Warum heißt es *im Dunkel**n*** (*Er saß im Dunkeln auf dem Boden*), wenn das Paradigma *dem Dunkel* aufweist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das sind zwei unterschiedliche Phänomene mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen.

Das erste, das, was man normalerweise unter "substantivierten Adjektiven" versteht, ist
essentiell ein Bedeutungswechsel. Die Deklination bleibt unverändert. Ein "Deutscher" wird zwar als Substantiv empfunden, es dekliniert aber vollständig wie ein Adjektiv und zeigt daher die Besonderheiten dieser Deklination, wie z.B. "Ein Deutsch**er**" vs "Der Deutsch**e**" und dass es eine weibliche Form gibt, die aber den gleichen Plural aufweist.
Es bedeutet normalerweise nicht mehr als "etwas, das {Adj.} ist" bzw. "jmd, der {Adj.} ist".

Beim zweiten, wie bei "Rot", "Dunkel", wird der Stamm des Adjektivs direkt als neutrales Nomen aufgefasst. Diese Art der Wortbildung nennt sich [Konversion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konversion_(Linguistik)). Es dekliniert daher genau wie ein normales neutrales Nomen. So gebildete Worte beschreiben aber das Konzept, das durch das Adjektiv ausgedrückt wird. Es bedeutet also grob "das {Adj.} sein". Da es grundsätzlich erst einmal das Konzept ausdrückt (und damit unzählbar ist), haben diese Nomen keinen Plural. Das geht auch für andere Wortarten, es gibt z.B. "das Ich".

Zu Dunkel: Bei "im Dunkeln" ist es tatsächlich das substantivierte Adjektiv. Man ist also "an einem dunklen Ort". Das Wort "Das Dunkel" ist gehoben
(siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dunkel)) und tatsächlich gibt es auch "im Dunkel".

> Im Dunkel dieses Zimmers kann man das Fürchten kriegen.

Das Problem ist nur, dass bei

> Er saß im Dunkel auf dem Boden.

der Eindruck entstehen kann, dass "das Dunkel auf dem Boden" eine Einheit ist. Das passiert bei der festen Wendung "im Dunkeln" nicht.

Die Kernfrage war ja, warum es unterschiedliche Deklinationen gibt. Ich lade andere herzlich dazu ein, die Frage "im Dunkel" vs. "im Dunklen" genauer zu erklären.

Comment: In short: there are **two** nouns, _das Dunkel_ and _das Dunkle_. (And there is even a third, more obscure derivation, via Umlaut: _Dünkel_, _Röte_.)